# Intersection of a dense subspace with closed subspaces in Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Give an example of a dense subspace $H_0$ of a Hilbert space $H$ and a closed subspace $Z$ of $H$ such that both $Z$ and $Z^\perp$ are infinite dimensional and $H_0 \cap Z = H_0 \cap Z^\perp = (0)$.

Comment:  The question was motivated by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2492637/prove-that-a-certain-subspace-m-of-space-c-00-cdot-2-is-closed-and/2492854#2492854) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545705/is-intersection-of-a-dense-subspace-and-a-closed-subspace-of-a-hilbert-space-als/1546849#1546849) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1425511/hilbert-space-dense-orthogonal-complement).   I know how to solve it, I'm offering it as an exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $H$ be $L^2[0,1]$, $H_0$ the polynomials, $Z$ the functions vanishing on $\left[0,\frac12\right]$, so $Z^\perp$ the functions vanishing on $\left[\frac12,1\right]$.